# Sort Core Data request ascending

Tags: objective-c, xcode, core-data, nsfetchrequest

I am trying to sort ascending my fetch request using the "groupID" that is of type string but inside of it is saved a number, under the form of counter, the problem is that the returned array is not "proper" sorted, not as i will like it to be, because it returns the elements sorted as: 0, 1, 10, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 instead of the expected 0, 1, 2, 3 ... 9, 10

I managed to find two solutions:
1 - modify the core data attribute from string to int (most unwanted scenario)
or
2 - make a fetch for all elements from core data, retrieve all of them in an array, use the size of the array to run a for loop, and inside of the for loop make another fetch with predicate using the for loop counter, and the returned entity I can save in an array, so by doing all of these I will get a sorted array with the entities

And here is my current code:

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"SuggestedChannelsEntity" inManagedObjectContext:context];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

NSSortDescriptor *sort = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"groupID" ascending:YES];
NSArray *sortDescription = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sort, nil];
[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescription];

NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *fetchedObjects = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use one of the sort selectors, 'localizedStandardCompare:', like this:

```
NSSortDescriptor *sort = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"groupID" ascending:YES selector:@selector(localizedStandardCompare:)];
```

This seems to work OK provided the numbers are not negative.

Comment: thank you for your answer can you also provide a link to some documentation? That will be much appreciated :)

Comment: Apple documentation: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/SortDescriptors/Articles/Creating.html

Comment: @LaurStefan See the Sort Descriptor documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/SortDescriptors/Articles/Creating.html), specifically the section entitled "Specifying Custom Comparisons", and the Core Data Programming Guide section on Persistent Store Features [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdPersistentStores.html), specifically the section on "FetchPredicates and Sort Descriptors".